# Arraylist Multiply values together not performing as expected

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Value which I am trying to Multiply together but when I try to calculate, it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
  double calAnswer = 0;
  for (int x =0; x < cal.size(); x++){
     calAnswer *= Integer.parseInt(cal.get(x));
  }

  System.out.println("ANSWER IS: "+calAnswer);
```

My `calAnswer` is outputting as 0.0.

But when I change my code to: `calAnswer += Integer.parseInt(cal.get(x));` The `calAnswer` outputs the correct sum of the values. It just doesn't work for the mulitplication. Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: hey dude, of course it return zero, This is simple mathematics principle. So give this some value lets say 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you start `calAnswer` with 0. Initialize it as:

```
double calAnswer = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

`0 * everyNumber` is always 0.

Change from

```
 double calAnswer = 0;
```

to

```
 double calAnswer = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

It would work fine

```
 double calAnswer = 1;
  for (int x =0; x < cal.size(); x++){
     calAnswer *= Integer.parseInt(cal.get(x));
  }

  System.out.println("ANSWER IS: "+calAnswer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change first line to:

```
double calAnswer = 1;
```